# Which user between the wasadmin user and the root user is recommended to install IBM Installation Manager 1.8 on Linux?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

Which user between the wasadmin (nonroot) user and the root user is recommended to install IBM Installation Manager 1.8 on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

There is no recommendation available on this. Most of the cases, I have seen wasadmin user for installation of all IBM products.

Advantage with root is, if you see any risk of getting deleted IM by mistake, while installing products with same user, then go for root.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I went with wasadmin. I figured it should be treated just like any other WAS products.